# Optimal control problems in fluid mechanics with system dynamics as ODEs

Tags: fluid-dynamics, optimal-control

I am searching for optimal control examples in fluid mechanics in which only ordinary differential equations are considered (i.e., in system dynamics or model of optimal control problem) with exact or approximate state and control variable plots. So far, I am getting examples containing PDEs. Does anyone know of any sources (books, journal articles) containing such examples?